# Blending colors GD - PHP

Tags: php, gd

Ok, I have a 64x64 pixels image, some pixels are white, some are grey, and some darker, so I have another 64x64 pixel image with some yellow pixels which will determine which pixels of the first image must be changed.
So far I could change the colors on the first image with the following code, but the thing is I have no idea how to "blend" the given color with the colors that were already on the first image.

For example, if a pixel is white (255,255,255) and the new color is red (255,0,0) the result will be (255,0,0) but if the pixel is a bit darker, the new red should also be darker. Any ideas?

```
$image = 'o1.png';
$overlay = 'o2.png';

$background = imagecreatefrompng($image);

imagealphablending($background, true);

// Create overlay image
$overlay = imagecreatefrompng($overlay);

// get size
$size = getimagesize("o2.png");
$L=$size[0];
$H=$size[1];

for($j=0;$j<$H;$j++){
    for($i=0;$i<$L;$i++){

        $rgb = imagecolorat($overlay, $i, $j);

        $red = (isset($_GET['r']) ? $_GET['r'] : 0);
        $green = (isset($_GET['g']) ? $_GET['g'] : 0);
        $blue = (isset($_GET['b']) ? $_GET['b'] : 0);

        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

        if(($r==255)&&($g==255)&&($b==0)) {

            $color = imagecolorallocate($background, $red, $green, $blue);
            imagesetpixel($background, $i, $j, $color);

        }

    }
}


header("Content-type: image/png");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=" . $image);

imagepng($background);

// Destroy the images
imagedestroy($background);
imagedestroy($overlay);
```

Comment: Why not just merge a an alpha image over the top instead?

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is I will never get the right color because it depends on the transparency %, I was hoping for some kind of code to "sum" both colors and get a color depending on the original pixel in the first image. If the transparency is too low, the darker parts of the original image wont be noticed, if it is too high, the new color, for example red will look more like an orange than a red.

Comment: Yes, of course... that's what merging an alpha image on top will do.  What is your question?

Comment: Yea, but don't you have to set a transparency level for it? If the transparency is too low, the darker parts of the original image wont be noticed, if it is too high, the new color, for example red will look more like an orange than a red.

Comment: Yes, isn't that what you want?  I don't have a clue what you are asking for, if you are asking for anything other than blending two 64x64 pixel images, considering that's what the title and body of your post say.  Can you clarify at all?

Comment: You might look at imagecopymerge() http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php  Hopefully it helps?

Comment: Actually, the title is blending colors, not images. I already tried merging the images, but it doesn't have the effect I want.
This is what I want, if a pixel on the first image is lets say (200,200,200) which is grey and the new color is red (255,0,0) then the result color should be a darker red, not a normal 255,0,0 red. If I use merging to do that, the result red will depend on the transparency I set and not on being darker/whiter depending on the original pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about multiply blend mode. The formula for this according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply) is:

> Result Color = (Top Color) * (Bottom Color) /255

Using this formula the resulting image will be darker where the background color is darker.

Comment: It's could be not obvious, but the formula should be applied to each component of the color(ie red, green, blue) separately(for I thought I need to multiply `0xFFFFFF` with `0xFF3333` which is not the same tough looks somewhat similar)