# PHP GD - blendmode alpha calculation

Tags: php, gd, alpha

I have the problem if I change my calculation for alpha in imagecolorallocatealpha
is it wrong.

Image 1:  [image]

Image 2: [image]

Image 3: [image]

Image 4: [image]

Image 5: [image]

The pictures from 1 - 3 are put together and look like this:

[image]

If pictures 4 and 5 are added, it looks like this:

[image]

You can now see the golden scales and the gray scales on the body, but that's wrong. The gray scales on the body should not be there.

In reality, the dragon should look like this:

[image]

The gray scales on the body should be bright and the golden scales should remain as they are.

@Syscall already helped with the "alpha" function in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49100534/7779838) and it works good but now we think the "blendmode" function is wrong.

```
function blendmode($dst, $src)
{
    $w = imagesx($src);
    $h = imagesy($src);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {
            $rgbDst = imagecolorsforindex($dst, imagecolorat($dst, $x, $y));
            $rgbSrc = imagecolorsforindex($src, imagecolorat($src, $x, $y));

            $r = min($rgbSrc['red'] + $rgbDst['red'], 255);
            $g = min($rgbSrc['green'] + $rgbDst['green'], 255);
            $b = min($rgbSrc['blue'] + $rgbDst['blue'], 255);

            imagesetpixel($src, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($src, $r, $g, $b, 204 / 255 * 105));
        }
    }

    return $src;
}
```

This is how the dragon looks like with buggy "blendmode" function:

[image]

Comment: Tell me, `$src` is "image3"? which is `$dst`? Thank you. And why images does not have the same size?

Comment: @Syscall i edited this thread and hope you can understand this better. :)

Comment: The question looks better now :), but I'm sorry, I haven't the solution to your issue. Maybe this post could helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8058658/9193372

Comment: What's mean "Top Color" and "Bottom color"?

Comment: Sorry again, my knowledge about it is really limited. Hope you'll find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bgd%5D+blend).

Comment: @Syscall maybe this helped you for helping me? :D
http://www.deepskycolors.com/archive/2010/04/21/formulas-for-Photoshop-blending-modes.html

Comment: @Syscall I found a bit. Your "alpha"-Function is wrong. If I remove your function first the black transparent background is gone.

Answer (score -1):

first at all I would recommend you not sticking on the builtin Graphic Libraries for php.

I would recommend you the ImageMagik (Imagick) or Intervention (http://image.intervention.io/).

They are a lot more powerfull libraries.

Comment: It helps the original poster more if you demonstrate how those libs could do more for their question, instead of just naming them.